# What happens if I just 'vectorizer.transform(phrase)' without fitting it?

Tags: transform, vectorization, sentiment-analysis, text-analysis, countvectorizer

Some things are confusing to me when it comes to vectorizing phrases and put them into a matrix form.

When you import either CountVectorizer or TfidfVectorizer,

what are the differences of .fit & .transform & .fit_transform  functions?

**I know '.fit' will learn the ngrams, split into ngrams.**

**'.transform' will put it into a phrase x ngram matrix.**

**'.fit_transform' works as a combination of .fit & .transform**

If this is the case, **what happens if I just vectorize.transform(phrase) without fitting it?**

I saw this tutorial set up which fit & transform the train data but for the test data, it only does 'transform' operation for the prediction.

Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: Seems to be a machine learning conceptual question. `Fitting` is the process in `training` phase where the necessary weights are trained to align with the ngrams (in your domain). After the model is fitted, `transform` (in your domain) tests the functionality of your model when applied to real-life test cases.

Comment: @Jerry Thank you Jerry for your reply. So, what would be the difference if I just "vectorizer.transform(x_test)" without fitting it ?

Comment: What is the framework/programming-languague you are using? I can look into it and give you a precise answer.

Comment: @Jerry Thank you very much Jerry, Im using Python. Doing sentiment analysis on Movie reviews using dataset from Rotten Tomatoes.

Answer (score 3):

Highlights:

1. `.transform(X)` = Transform dictionary features into 2D feature matrix.
2. `.fit_transform(X)` = learn feature names + `.transform(X)`

To answer your question:

You can `.transform` only after learning the features using `.fit`. Directly applying `.transform` will ignore any features not encoutered in `.fit` and hence, would not output any classification results.

References:

- According to the documentation in http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.transform , `.transform(X)` converts any `dict X` (mapping `feature_name` to `feature_values`) into a 2-D feature matrix. The 2D matrix is the correct way (according to vector math) to input entries to a classifier.
- According to http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.fit_transform , `.fit_transform(X,y=None)` first, learns the list of feature names in the input `dict X` (the term for the process of learning is called `fitting`) and second, applies the `transform` procedures stated in the previous paragraph.